# Swap extra mouse buttons on Windows?

Tags: windows, mouse, button-remapping

I have a mouse which has two extra buttons at the lateral to navigate back or forward.

I want to swap the functionality of these extra buttons. I could do it in Lubuntu using `xmodmap` as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/151819/355686), by permuting the `8` and `9` button codes:

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8 10 11 12 13"
```

Is there a trick to do the same on Windows 10?

Comment: A lot of mice have their own utilities for managing button functions.  Did you check the manufacturer's website?

Comment: @Hydraxan14 I searched but it seems they don't have any webpage. It's an Owlotech MS-200 mouse, from New Alternative Technologies SL. I only found http://www.newalttech.com/, which is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Generic 3rd-Party Options

I don't know of any built-in Windows way to do this, but a blog post over at [Raymond.cc](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/changing-and-customizing-your-mouse-buttons-actions/) offers some 3rd-party options like Mouse Manager, HydraMouse, X-Mouse Button Control, and ClickMouse.

I've never used any of these before (I usually use the mouse manufacturer's utility), but I think [Mouse Manager](https://realityripple.com/Software/Applications/Mouse_Manager/) looks like a nice, simple option that lets you remap mouse buttons.

Comment: I tried Mouse Manager but when it seems it can only map the buttons to keys, not to buttons.

Comment: X-Mouse Button Control did the trick.

Comment: X-Mouse-button Control is my goto application for this too. Also to DISABLE those extra buttons completely. On some mice I keep hitting those buttons accidentally. Disabling them completely makes life a lot easier in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but...  [Raxer](https://github.com/BracoZS/Raxer) is a small proyect on github for Windows (7 or higher) that does just that (**swaps the functionality of these extra buttons**). It is very simple just run it and it will start working and does not require configuration. I use it for the same purpose you want.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.